# How to change a Windows Service permission programmatically?

Tags: c#

I have a simple Windows Service running on my computer. I want to start/stop it from inside a Windows application named ServiceManager. I already can do that when I run the ServiceManager with admin privileges. Is it possible to do the same thing without the admin privileges? 
Maybe changing some permissions in the service. If it is possible, how can I do that?
By the way I am programming in C# language.

Comment: google is your friend: http://www.dscentral.in/2011/10/11/allow-non-admin-control-windows-service/#.VgFcuPlVhHw

Comment: @yms that would work, but I would have to do that in all the computers that I have running my Service right? I needed somthing that would change the service itself, so everytime I installed the service in a new computer it would be controlled by my ServiceManager properly. But that was a nice hint, now I have a new horizon to look at. Thanks.

Comment: I see, I guess you will need to find a way to do this programmatically during the installation of your services. You could configure the group "everyone" at that time to grant it access to your service, but that might not be a good idea from a "security" point of view